# WPF and WIndows 10. Invisible border around windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

When i tried to align my window by side or corner of display, i discovered that there are some kind of padding between edge of screen and edge of my window.
I had created new wpf project from template, added only two lines in constructor and got this:

[image]


Why it don't fit to the edge of screen? Same problem when i try to put window to the right bottom corner like this:

```cs
Rect workArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
Left = workArea.Location.X + workArea.Width - Width;
Top = workArea.Location.Y + workArea.Height - Height;
```

It looks like window has 7px border (just like on win7) but invisible on win10. Also i found that if i set both `WindowStyle` to `WindowStyle.None` and `ResizeMode` to `ResizeMode.NoResize`, the system places window correctly, but this is not what i need. On win7 same program works as expected.

Of cource i can set `Left` property to -7, but it is not a solution. How can i properly set window place, so that it will look well on both win7 and win10?

Comment: In case of right bottom case have you tried ActualWidth & ActualHeight properties(after the display)?

Comment: @KyloRen yes, result is same

Comment: may be "this.Left = 0 - SystemParameters.ResizeFrameVerticalBorderWidth - SystemParameters.FixedFrameVerticalBorderWidth; " can be used from programming point of view on window 10. Else you have to use ChromeWindow class I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The resizable border on the left/right/bottom is now invisible on Windows 10, and that border is where that gap is. If you put the window in the middle of the screen, and drag your mouse to the left edge of the window, you will see the cursor change to a resizing cursor for 8 pixels further out past the edge of the window. That tells you that the border still exists.

You can get the offests by using a combination of the normal `GetWindowRect` function and the use of the `DwmGetWindowAttribute` function, together with the `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

They leave the metrics the same (for example, the PaddedBorderWidth in the registry is still -60), and achieve the clear resize handles entirely in the theme ("Aero"). It's not glass, it's just outright invisible the way Office 2013 renders them.  Your application will *literally* draw at the same pixel coordinates on both Windows 7 and 10, only Windows 7 will have glass effects filling that gap.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to know whether have windows glass effect (and its thikness) or not to avoid that ugly gap?

Comment: Not by any means I'm aware of. Since the border size is being applied by the theme and not windowmetrics in the registry, I don't think you could even query that to determine. The first thing that comes to mind is just shift by however many pixels when the windows version is detected as 10 or greater.